# Player Camera and Map Scrolling not working as intended

Tags: c++, tilemap, rpg

I'm creating a top-down 2D rpg game in c++, and I can't seem to wrap my head around the concept of map scrolling.

My camera system is centered on the player every time my player moves, (cameraPos = playerPos - screen attributes/2), and everything else in the game is offset by the cameraPos in the render stage.

But then every time my player moves, it ends up "moving" twice, once from me pressing the movement key, and the second time from the camera system value offsetting every tile in the game.

[gif to movement without camera](https://media.giphy.com/media/LvHSHZANaUMhSQ2srY/giphy.gif)

[gif to movement with camera](https://media.giphy.com/media/o3NUep3DrfgPM36Ksh/giphy.gif)

What am I doing wrong? Any insight or feedback is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you use any framework?

Comment: Did you remember to offset the player sprite by the camera position, as you do with all other sprites/tiles? Showing us the code for a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example would help.

Comment: @DMGregory, and that just fixed the issue. I thought I'd already done that, and I'd commented the offset out for whatever reason.

Comment: @DMGregory, ok so I apparently can't upvote your comment to thank you, but hey, thanks a bunch 

Comment: Be sure to post your solution as an answer below, so it can help others dealing with similar issues. Showing code can be a big help too.